# Selenium Python find text on page and click next ahref link

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium to find the text 'APPELLANT'S BRIEF FILED" and then have selenium click the very next ahref link.  Below is the table class code on the page and the relevant td align code that I am focused on.

```
<table class="gridview" cellspacing="0" align="Center" 
       id="SheetContentPlaceHolder_caseDocket_gvDocketInformation"
       style="border-collapse:collapse;">
   <tbody><tr class="gridview_header">
```

This is the code I am focused on.

```
<tr style="background-color:Gainsboro;">
   <td align="left" valign="top" style="width:75px;">04/10/2015</td>
   <td align="left" valign="top">A1</td>
   <td align="left" valign="top">EV</td>
   <td align="left">**APPELLANT'S BRIEF FILED**. APPELLANT'S BRIEF</td>
   <td align="center">
       <a href="**DisplayImageList.aspx?q=IXEpMLEtUn6VTtFyd8FAyx5-hPNZuKfx0**" 
           target="_blank"><img src="images/ImageSheet.png" alt=""></a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you give the html as plain text?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to copy the html while viewing it via the Chrome console.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: there is a menu entry in the chrome context menu...or try ctrl+u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath `//td[contains(., "APPELLANT'S BRIEF FILED")]/following-sibling::td[1]/a`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//td[contains(., "APPELLANT'S BRIEF FILED")]/following-sibling::td[1]/a""")
```

Answer (score 0):

To find any text within the table e.g. **APPELLANT'S BRIEF FILED** and then have invoke `click()` on the very next *href* link you can write a function which will accept the desired text as an input and click on the next href as follows :

```
def test_me(string):
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[.='" + myString + "']//following::td[1]/a").click()
```

Now you can call the function `test_me()` from anywhere within your program with any of the text item from the table to click on the relevant *href* as follows :

```
test_me("APPELLANT'S BRIEF FILED")
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks.  One follow up that appeared.  Any mechanism to search for two words on the same line?  For example, driver.find_elements_by_xpath("... contains 'APPELLANT" and "FILED.")

Comment: Found the answer to my secondary question above.  So, here it is for anyone else wondering...  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'APPELLANT') and contains(text(), 'BRIEF')]/following-sibling::td[1]/a").click()